# How do I get a view_context in my controller specs for testing active model serializers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, active-model-serializers

I setup this UserSerializer

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :first_name, :last_name, :email, :abilities

  delegate :current_user, to: :scope
  delegate :current_client, to: :scope

  def abilities
    object.client_roles.where(client_id: current_client.id)
  end
end
```

and this from my ApplicationController

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base   
  serialization_scope :view_context

  protected 
  def current_client
      ....
```

I put in the "delegate" code based on [this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/409-active-model-serializers)  around 7:45

He then goes on to say that the downside is that the tests now need a view_context and gives a solution for using Test Unit.

When I run my specs I get one of two errors

> Failure/Error: get "show", :id => user.id, :format => :json
>        NoMethodError:
>          undefined method `current_client' for #<#:0x00000004f69f60>

or

> Failure/Error: data.active_model_serializer.new(data, {:root =>
>   name}).to_json
>        RuntimeError:
>          UserSerializer#current_client delegated to scope.current_client, but scope is nil:

How do I provide the view_context in my controller specs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK.  My fault.  I was calling the `UserSerializer` manually in my code later to do assertions.  That's what was throwing the error.  Fixed it just by adding:

```
before(:each) do
  UserSerializer.any_instance.stub(:scope => controller)
end
```

Comment: Where did you add this exactly?